# error while using mysql query inside the while loop for fetching a previous query

Tags: php, mysql, syntax, nested

I have 2 queries.
I am applying the first select query, and getting the results via the while loop using my_fetch_array, however, inside that while, I am using another select query, but at that point I am getting an error.

Can't I use another select inside the while ?

```
$i = 1;
$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT x, count(*) FROM table1 group by x ORDER BY count(*) desc");

while ($rowRes1= mysql_fetch_array($result1 ))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td ALIGN=CENTER style=width:5%>" . $i . "</td>";
echo "<td ALIGN=CENTER style=width:40%>" . $rowRes1['0'] . "</td>";
echo "<td ALIGN=CENTER style=width:10%>" . $rowRes1['1'] . "</td>";

$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT x FROM data where x = $rowRes1['0'] ORDER BY y ASC LIMIT 1")

while ($rowRes2= mysql_fetch_array($result2 ))
{ 
echo "<td ALIGN=CENTER style=width:10%>" .     $rowRes2['0'] . "</td>";
}
$i++;
}
```

Comment: general tip: if you get an error, TELL US WHAT THE ERROR IS. The `$rowRes1['0']` in your second query is a PHP syntax buglet - you cannot use quoted array keys in a double-quoted string like that. You are also generating horrible html. `CETER` is not a valid alignment value, and your styles are unquoted. Your two queries also could trivially be re-written as a single query.

Comment: Error #1: Using `mysql_query` in new code. Don't do this. It's a deprecated interface that is being removed in future versions of PHP. Use [PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) instead if you can. Error #2: Improper [SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php).

Comment: @MarcB thanks alot for your feedback. I am a newbie in php and just starting around. the CENTER alignment value was a typo which got corrected. I also fixed the quoted array key inside the double quotes.
however, can you write (if possible) both queries in a single query, as I would like to use it for referance.

Comment: @tadman should I have used mysqli_query instead of mysql_query ? Since when they are deprecated and any ideas if they will be out ?

Comment: The deprecation notice is in a giant red box in [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php). `mysqli` is a good alternative if PDO is not available, but otherwise, use PDO. PHP 5.5 issues warnings for using `mysql_query`. PHP 5.6 may remove it completely.

Comment: @tadman thanks a lot for sharing from your experience. Time to read some stuff :)

Answer (score 1):

PHP cannot interpret strings containing array accessors like $rowRes1['1'] within double quoted strings.

store the data in another variable like $rowRes1Col = $rowRes1['0']; and use that inside the string.